# Using check constraints in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a check constraint on a stored procedure where the invoice date can't go before January 1st 1990 and can't go ahead of December 31st 9999.

Right now I have my SQL script setup like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[getBalanceByDueDateRange]
    @MINDATE DATETIME = '1990-01-01 00:00:00',
    @MAXDATE DATETIME = '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
AS       
    SELECT  
        i.InvoiceID AS 'Invoice ID',
        v.VendorID AS 'Vendor ID',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR (12), i.InvoiceDueDate, 107) AS 'Invoice Due Date',
        ABS(i.InvoiceTotal - i.PaymentTotal) AS 'Balance'
    FROM 
        dbo.[Vendors] v
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.[Invoices] i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
    WHERE   
        i.InvoiceDueDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@MINDATE, i.InvoiceDate) AND ISNULL(@MAXDATE, i.InvoiceDate)
    ORDER BY 
        i.InvoiceDueDATE ASC;
```

What I would like it to do is return an error if the `MINDATE` or the `MAXDATE` are not within that range. I'm thinking I might have to use IF/ELSE statements but is there another way like using `CHECK CONSTRAINT`? The stored procedure does work (in that it returns nothing) but I want it to be a little bit more effective and professional. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear it.

Comment: `IF`/`ELSE` were designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Constraints constrain the *data*, not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon Linoff's suggestion I figured it out, thanks Gordon!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[getBalanceByDueDateRange]
    @MINDATE DATETIME   = '1990-01-01 00:00:00' 
,       @MAXDATE DATETIME   = '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
AS
IF @MINDATE < '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
RAISERROR ('Please Select a Valid Date',0,1)
ELSE IF  @MAXDATE > '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
RAISERROR ('Please Select a Valid Date',0,1)
ELSE IF @MINDATE > @MAXDATE
RAISERROR ('The Minimum Date can`t be later than the Maximum Date',0,1)
ELSE
SELECT  i.InvoiceID AS 'Invoice ID'
,       v.VendorID AS 'Vendor ID' 
,       CONVERT(VARCHAR (12),i.InvoiceDueDate,107)AS 'Invoice Due Date'
,       ABS(i.InvoiceTotal - i.PaymentTotal) AS 'Balance'
FROM dbo.[Vendors] v
INNER JOIN dbo.[Invoices] i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
WHERE   i.InvoiceDueDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@MINDATE, i.InvoiceDate) AND
        ISNULL(@MAXDATE, i.InvoiceDate)
ORDER BY i.InvoiceDueDATE ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RaiseError and return from procedure as below. As Brandon mentioned Constraints are not for code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[getBalanceByDueDateRange]
        @MINDATE DATETIME   = '1990-01-01 00:00:00' 
,       @MAXDATE DATETIME   = '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
AS       
BEGIN
    IF @MINDATE > @MAXDATE 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('MinDate is greater than MaxDate', 20, -1)
        RETURN
    END
    SELECT  i.InvoiceID AS 'Invoice ID'
    ,       v.VendorID AS 'Vendor ID' 
    ,       CONVERT(VARCHAR (12),i.InvoiceDueDate,107)AS 'Invoice Due Date'
    ,       ABS(i.InvoiceTotal - i.PaymentTotal) AS 'Balance'
    FROM dbo.[Vendors] v
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Invoices] i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
    WHERE   i.InvoiceDueDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@MINDATE, i.InvoiceDate) AND
            ISNULL(@MAXDATE, i.InvoiceDate)
    ORDER BY i.InvoiceDueDATE ASC;
END
```